# .htaccess changes URL when trailing slash is omitted

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, trailing-slash

I have a multiple sites in one root domain with `.htaccess`. There is my

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.0\.6$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/192.168.0.6/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /192.168.0.6/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site1\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/192.168.0.6/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /192.168.0.6/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/site2.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2.com/$1 [L]
```

When I go to `http://sub.site1.org/files/` it works, but when I go to `http://sub.site1.org/files` (without a slash), it redirects me to `http://sub.site1.org/192.168.0.6/files`.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/192.168.0.6/` will never match because `REQUEST_URI` doesn't  start with host name.  Your #3 rule seems to work fine. Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # RULE#2
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site1\.org$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/192.168.0.6/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /192.168.0.6/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> When I go to `http://sub.site1.org/files/` it works, but when I go to `http://sub.site1.org/files` (without slash), it redirects me to `http://sub.site1.org/192.168.0.6/files`

You would seem to have a conflict with mod_dir. If `/files` exists as a physical directory at `/192.168.0.6/files` then mod_dir will append the trailing slash with a 301 redirect (in order to "fix" the URL) *after* the URL has been rewritten, thus exposing the rewritten URL. (You should be seeing a trailing slash on the redirected URL.)

You need to manually append the trailing slash *before* the request is rewritten, by checking whether the URL would map to a directory at the new location.

If `/files` is the only directory that is likely to receive these types of requests then you could simply hardcode this. For example:

```
# Append slash to "/files"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site1\.org$
RewriteRule ^files$ /$0/ [R=301,L]

# RULE#2 (Updated) - Rewrite request to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site1\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/192.168.0.6/
RewriteRule (.*) /192.168.0.6/$1 [L]
```

NB: You were missing the start-of-string anchor (`^`) on the second *condition* that matches the subdirectory.

You need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect by mod_dir will have been cached by the browser.

For this reason it is recommended to test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Otherwise, for a more general, any directory solution then something like the following would be required:

```
# Append slash to subdirectory BEFORE rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site1\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/192.168.0.6/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/192.168.0.6/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# RULE#2 (Updated) - Rewrite request to subdirectory
# (as above)
```

The same issue potentially applies to **RULE#1** and **RULE#3** as well. Note that **RULE#1** and **RULE#2** are essentially the same and could (should) be combined.

Currently, in the rules as posted, there's nothing stopping a user from accessing the "hidden" subdirectory directly (if this should be known). You might consider redirecting the user if they should stumble upon this "hidden" subdirectory.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994418/369434) to a similar question that goes into more detail (although that question is dealing with just one "site").

- [URL masking not working for URLs that omit the trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990152/url-masking-not-working-for-urls-that-omit-the-trailing-slash)